# What to do for the problem of " not part of any active accounts" error while opening IBM Watson Studio?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-studio

I am not able to use Watson Studio. While opening it, I'm getting the error of " You are not part of any active account ". I created my account as a part of coursera studies. Even I tried using different emails but getting the same error. What should I do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an issue for Watson support and not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

You may have switch account after login if you belong to multiple accounts. You would see a drop-down and an avatar icon at top right corner of the page. Make sure you select the right account and in "profile and settings", its set to right resource grp and org.

https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/admin/personal-settings.html